The integral of $\frac{\arctan^2(x)}{x}$ and $\frac{\log(1+x^2) \arctan(x)}{x}$
I was doing some harmonic series and happened to stumble upon the fine result $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n} x^n=\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-x), \quad |x|<1$$ I played around with it a bit and obtained the two elegant results, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_{2n}}{2n}x^{2n}=\frac{1}{2}\arctan^2(x)+\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right), \quad |x|\le1$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_{2n-1}}{2n-1} x^{2n-1}=\operatorname{Ti}_2(x)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+x^2)\arctan(x), \quad |x|\le1$$ where $\displaystyle\log(z)=\log_e(z)$ is the natural logarithm function, $\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=-\int_0^z\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^2}$ is the Dilogarithm function and $\displaystyle\operatorname{Ti}_2(z)=\int_0^z\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^2}$ is the Inverse tangent integral. I then made the change in variable $x=t$, multiplied on both sides by $1/t$ and integrated from $t=0$ to $t=x$ and obtained $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^2}x^{2n}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x\frac{\arctan^2(t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t+\cdots$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^2} x^{2n-1}=\cdots -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x\frac{\log(1+t^2)\arctan(t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ the rest of the integrals being unimportant. I tried integrating the first integral by parts and found, $$\int_0^x\frac{\arctan^2(t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\operatorname{Ti}_2(x)\arctan(x)-\int_0^x\frac{\operatorname{Ti}_2(t)}{t^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ and I got stuck. Of course, I can make the substitution $t=\tan(y)$ but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Furthermore, I tried doing the second integral by noting that $$\int_0^x\frac{\log(1+t^2)\arctan(t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\log(1+x^2)\operatorname{Ti}_2(x)-2\int_0^x\frac{t\operatorname{Ti}_2(t)}{t^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ which leaves me with an even "scarier looking" integral. So my question is, how do I evaluate both integrals or one of them? What am I missing?

The first one is very nasty

@ClaudeLeibovici Indeed!

First, I wouldn't say I like that much to answer questions alike coming from apparently new users. Secondly, the solutions are straightforward (with the proper results in hand).
The ideas:
We need that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n \frac{H_n}{n^2}$$
$$=\zeta(2)\log(1-x)-\frac{1}{2}\log(x)\log^2(1-x)-\log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$$
$$+\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$
$$
=2\zeta(2)\log(1-x)+\frac{1}{6}\log^3(1-x)-\log(x)\log^2(1-x)-\log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$$
$$
-2\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)+2\zeta(3) 
$$
$$=2\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)-\log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\frac{1}{6}\log^3(1-x),\tag1$$
which appears in this form in More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series: A New Collection of Fiendish Problems and Surprising Solutions (2023), where based on our needs we consider the more convenient form and then replace $x$ by $i x$ and take the real part, and the imaginary part respectively.
For example, if we consider
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_{2n}}{2n}x^{2n}=\frac{1}{2}\arctan^2(x)+\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right),$$
which also appears in the mentioned book, on page $97$, and further apply Landen's identity, and continue this way the calculations in OP, we arrive at classical results, and the first desired extraction of the generalized integral is done.
Regarding the use of $(1)$, the form we get can be further rearranged.
End of story (btw, more options are possible)

Nice solution. Believe it or not, I did think of this approach. The reason why I didn't explore it further is that I was looking for a more "natural" way of evaluating the integral(s) since Mathematica gives a bizarre-looking closed form for the first integral. So I wanted to obtain that very same closed form by evaluating the integral in the "traditional way." Nevertheless, thanks for your solution.

You stated at the end of your solution that there are other options. What are they, if you don't mind me asking?

Utmost gratitude. I don't see the connection between them (the ones you provided above) and the integrals I'm seeking at the moment, but I'll take a closer look at them as soon as I get the chance.   Cheers.

@KaraboDibakoane The integrals in the comments were pretty much overkill in light of the second solution. No need for them since one can do everything much simpler and faster as seen in the other answer.

A lightning strike solution (or mind-blowing if you want to)
Start with
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+xt)}{t}\textrm{d}t$$
$$=-\frac{1}{3}\log^3(1+x)-2\log(1+x)\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)+2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right),$$
as seen in More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series: A New Collection of Fiendish Problems and Surprising Solutions (2023), page 534,
and the next step here is to replace $x$ by $y x$, let the variable change $x t \mapsto t$, and then let $y=i$, and take the real and imaginary parts.
End of Story
Many thanks, Cornel!

Sounds like I'm gonna have one hell of a time.  Nice one. I'll do the computation tomorrow though.  I had a long day. Thanks for your help once again. ✌️ Ciao for now.
